# How do I send SMSes from my computer through an Android phone?

Tags: android, sms, htc-hero

I have an [HTC Hero](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTC_Hero) Android (European version) unlocked phone. Is there an app that will let me type away all my text messages on my PC and send the SMSes directly from the PC through my phone?

I'm basically looking at something like a Nokia PC Suite's equivalent.

Comment: Should this be migrated to http://android.stackexchange.com ?

Comment: @IlariKajaste no, question is ontopic for [su]

Comment: check out [AirDroid](http://airdroid.com/)

Comment: [http://www.wondershare.com/android-manager/](http://www.wondershare.com/android-manager/) - I added it as an answer and I think it's best for the money (free) =)

Comment: Try [Browser SMS Messenger](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.browsersms)

Comment: Similar question on "Android Enthusiasts": http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/4738/how-can-i-be-informed-through-my-computer-if-a-new-sms-is-received

Answer (score 33, accepted):

I've looked at DesktopSMS, EasySMS, RemoteSMS, Droid Messenger, MightyText and BrowserTexting.

Droid Messenger has you go through their website, which is a deal breaker for anyone who cares about the privacy of their text messages.

DekstopSMS is full of bugs and hasn't been maintained since August 2009.

I haven't tried RemoteSMS but the free version only supports WiFi and at work my laptop is on a network that my Android can't access, so I couldn't use it there.

[EasySMS](http://www.fireblade.org/EasySMS/) was the winner so far. Free with an option to donate 1 EUR for messages longer than 160 chars, with author actively working on the few outstanding issues, SMS threads are displayed in the browser over a local connection to the phone (no information leaves the phone or your computer). Worked fine over USB, including the in-browser notifications of new SMSes. Shows incoming MMSes. On the down-side, it can't mark as read on the phone the messages you have read in the browser, so if you have a notification LED flashing for incoming texts, it will keep flashing until you read the message on the Android.

[BrowserTexting](http://www.browsertexting.com/) is free (but not open source) and uses AES end-to-end encryption between browser and the Android. The website doesn't explain exactly how it works, but presumably the android app and your web browser both connect to the browsertexting.com server. Features include no need to have mobile on same network as the computer, desktop and sound notifications, Chrome extension, bulk SMS, autosync with the phone's Inbox etc. No mention of MMS support.

[MightyText](http://www.mightytext.net/) is a lot like browsertexting. Free. No info about security. More confusing GUI, less features and a bit more buggy. Unfortunately with signup, but a lot of users and also chrome extension. Also worth a try.

Comment: been meaning to update this for sometime. EasySMS has the advantage of being free and also support Bluetooth/USB, clearly the winner among 3. Though I might add i fee RemoteSMS is slightly more stable.

Comment: Yeah, EasySMS is nice, except that it currently (2011-06) cannot send to many recipients at once and it isn't opensource: https://bitbucket.org/easysms/easysms/issue/29/open-source

Comment: I've approved the edit above because it seemed to provide some useful information to a very outdated topic (and unfortunately the question is protected).

Comment: EasySMS no longer seems to work (2015)

Answer (score 5):

You could try [RemoteSMS](http://www.appszoom.com/android_applications/communication/remotesms-pro_kdx.html). It is pretty simple, and no registration is needed.

Notes: It creates a web server (accessible to anyone on the network, I might add) accessible via your Web browser via the phone's IP address and port 8080.

Comment: .. and an extra virtual lolly-pop for you jay. Surprised such a useful app hasn't come up in the blogging/review circles. Many thanks!

Comment: Link is broken.

Answer (score 4):

Self promoting never hurts:

I had the same problem, so I wrote TextToCloud. It comes with a small PHP file you install onto your own private web server, and it connects to that.

It's free at https://market.android.com/details?id=uk.co.jcitbournemouth.texttocloud

Oh, the cool thing is it still works even if you're outside Wifi range of your phone.. :)

Answer (score 3):

You can now do that through gtalk or XMPP with

- GTalkSMS:
  https://code.google.com/p/gtalksms
  for Android >= 2.0
- TalkMyPhone:
  https://code.google.com/p/talkmyphone/
  for Android < 2.0

Answer (score 3):

I strongly recommend [MyPhone Explorer](http://www.fjsoft.at/en/), Just install the myphone explorer client on the phone and that is it!

Comment: Had this question favorited so noticed your response. Yes! This is an absolute win! No web server, and even a portable installation, thanks tico!

Comment: MyPhoneExplorer has a number of bugs I reported back in February, which the author hasn't fixed yet.

http://www.fjsoft.at/forum/viewtopic.php?p=58630#58630

http://www.fjsoft.at/forum/viewtopic.php?p=58416

Comment: @dandv I don't experience the first: I do not see numbers, I see names. Haven't tested the (calendar related) second.

Comment: MyPhone Explorer is not available for Linux.

Answer (score 2):

[MAXS](http://projectmaxs.org) (Modular Android XMPP Suite) allows you to send SMS messages over [XMPP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XMPP). It also allows you to control various aspects of Android, includes a SMS/Call/Battery notification and reply system. Additionally it is able to send and receive files to and from your Android device. There are many other features too.

Using XMPP as transport, the "desktop app" can be every XMPP Client. Which is one of the big advantages of MAXS, as it does not need a dedicated desktop app. Although there may be one in the future.

<sup>Note: According to the FAQ I have to disclose that I am involved into MAXS. MAXS is an open source GPLv3 licensed Android app. Everyone can contribute.</sup>

Comment: I heard about MAXS, but it was the SMS functionality advertised in this post, that got me using it. The app is great, you guys are doing an awesome job ! *thumbs-up*

Comment: Thanks. Glad you like it. A new version of MAXS will be released in 1-2 weeks with new features, bug fixes and improved connection stability.

Comment: The technical work on MAXS is awesome, and I love the concept. The UX design is so complex LOL. I am a technical user and I'm having a hard time wrapping my head around the Quickstart guide which is the equivalent of several pages. I think a guide at all indicates the design could be improved. The product should be so good no guide is needed. Most apps don't come with instructions. :) But I did get it to work

Comment: Yeah, MAXS is mostly my personal playground which just happens to be available on some channels. As you may have already figured: UI is not my main focus, but patches are of course welcome. :-)

Answer (score 1):

It seems that [DroidMessenger](http://www.droidmessenger.com/) can do just that.

Answer (score 1):

My phone explorer is indeed great! Only disadvantage is that I can only send SMS with a max length of 2x160 tokens. If I do more it gives an error.

If you want to give the money, EasySMS is great as well!

An other option if you want to do everything from your PC as if you were on your phone is Droid VNC server. You can control and view the phone screen live from your PC.
This does lag slightly though.

Answer (score 1):

[Wondershare MobileGo](http://www.wondershare.com/android-manager/) is now the best thing out there and the closest match to Nokia PC Suite I can find. The free edition lets you view and compose SMS messages and manage contacts, music, movies, or photos.  Also no fee for longer messages. There is nothing to install on the device for USB connectivity and there is also the option for WiFi connectivity but with an app. The GUI is really tidy and the app is constantly updated by the developers. I feel this is closest match to answer this question.

Answer (score 0):

I have never of heard of what you're looking for, but if you're in a pinch Google allows SMS through your Gmail account and is independent of your phone. You have to enable the feature from Gmail Labs.

Comment: Only seems to work in the US

Comment: yup rodey only for the US folk. Not available for outside US

Answer (score 0):

Try [Mobile Cloud](http://cl4.mobi). I like it because it's easy to use. Enter any password in the app, automaticly get ID and you already can send messages from the site.

[image: enter pass] -> [image: send sms]

Answer (score 0):

A lot of these answers are dated.

Installing [Airdroid](http://airdroid.com) on your device is the latest way to do this as of 2015