# iMessage program for Windows or similar?

Tags: windows-7, iphone

iMessage (desktop app) is only for OS X and it's not clear if they'll bring it to Windows. I'd like to send text messages or iMessage texts using my computer. I have an iPhone iOS 5, jailbroken.

I came across this article which allows you to send text messages using the same phone number as your cell phone (*this is key*) through your computer, but it's only for Android. http://howto.cnet.com/8301-11310_39-57458789-285/send-texts-from-your-computer-with-mightytext/?tag=rb_content;main

Also found this question searching on SU but again only for Android.
[How do I send SMSes from my computer through an Android phone?](https://superuser.com/questions/86076/how-do-i-send-smses-from-my-computer-through-an-android-phone)

Windows 7

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Through the help of Reddit/r/iphone, I found this free app called Remote Messages that works only on jailbroken iPhones. It works if you're on the same WiFi network as your iPhone or if you connect the iPhone to your PC using USB. Just text through your web browser. Works on ios6 and iPhone 5.

http://www.remotemessages.com/

Comment: While this may solve the issue, its preferable to list the steps in the answer and provide the URL for reference

Answer (score 1):

Google Voice lets you send SMS messages from your web browser. Cross-platform since you can use it from your phone as well.

If that's not what you're looking for, need some detail - do you want to compose an SMS on your workstation and then send it using your phone?

Comment: Just as that CNet article states (but that's for Android). Send a text message from my computer, yet still using my cell phone number. Google Voice seems a little complicated because it involves terminating my service plan and porting my number and there's also issues with MMS.